# Correct way to adjust View from Controller event

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that handles authentication. I've declared a factory service called Authentication that has a login() method that makes an $http request to the REST API that returns a token.

The login() method has callback parameter. The controller handles the callback. Upon successful authentication I'd like to make adjustments to the DOM to hide the login form. (I'm using jQuery Mobile for my UI routing.) I don't want the controller to be messing with the DOM, so I've declared a factory service called View that I pass into the controller. The login() callback then calls View.hideLoginForm().

Is that the best way to maintain a separation of concerns - to pass in a service to the controller that is in charge of adjusting the view? It has made unit testing easy so there's at least that. Just wondering if anyone has an even better idea.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, a controller connects the scope and the logic. The scope itself connects the view with JS. A service is actually there for application logic (so what your `Authentication`-Service does), it shouldnt change the view directly.

So, to have a clean separation of concerns, i would rather change a variable `showLoginForm` in the controllers `$scope` and bind that variable to the DOM via the `ng-show`-Directive. Then you can just set `showLoginForm` to false and your view updates automatically.

This is also 100% testable, since you dont need to concern about any DOM manipulation.

Comment: Thanks Charminbear. I agree with you, but the change in variable would need to trigger a jQuery Mobile .navigate(). I suppose I could do that through a $watch, but I think I would rather encapsulate all the jQuery calls in a View service than have a bunch of $watch statements in my controller. The $watch solution would make testing difficult as well.

Comment: Well i dont have much experience with jQuery-Mobile. But usually, you would wrap 3rd-Party Libraries like jQuery inside a directive, since real DOM-Manipulations is to be put in directives. But well, in the end of the day, its about what works for you and your requirments. And if that means putting DOM-Manipulation in a service, then that it is. :)